# How to add Sharekit to existing project

Tags: iphone, sharekit

How to add sharekit to existing project for sharing on social networks.

Following instructions from sharekit wiki.

If i add sharekit.xcodeproj to my project i see only one target in share kit but in sharekit wiki it shows four targets.

When trying to add ShareKit's targets as depenedencies to your project's build phase: your project's app target - build phases - target dependencies add 2 new targets from ShareKit subproject: "Static Library" and "Resource Bundle". I dont find any static library and resource bundle.

Please help how to add sharekit in project.

Answer (score 0):

what i did to find these targets ;

Right click on your your project navigator in xCode, then choose Add files to ...
then choose submodules in your project folder and add.

[image]

After that you will find "Static Library" and "Resource Bundle" in targets dependencies.